# Find $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}JP$ where $A$ is the matrix of $f$ and J is the Jordan Form. $P$ non invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the Jordan Form and a basis of Jordan for the endomorphism of $R^4$
>
> $$f(x,y,z,t)=(x,x+y-t,-2x+y+z+2t,-x+2t)$$

After doing all the process, I find $P$ such that $A=P^{-1}JP$ where $A$ is the matrix of $f$ and $J$ is the Jordan Form.

My problem comes when I find $P=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix} $ which is a non invertibe and because of that I can't have $A=P^{-1}JP$

The A matrix is $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\ -2 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\-1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix} $ and its eigenvalues are $1$ and $2$.

I checked my calculus several times without finding an error. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting $P^{-1}AP=J$ where
\begin{align*}
P &=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right] &
J &=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Note that the columns of my $P$ are nearly identical to yours. Perhaps you've made an algebra error?

Comment: Right! The eigenvector for the eigenvalue 2 is missing one element.

Comment: Yes, I finally found it, in my case, the last column of P should be $(0,-1,1,1)^t$, my bad! Thank you for your answer, I found my error quick after you posted that P.